# What happened when I put an "=" sign inside of my mathematical operations?

Tags: vb.net, math, syntax

I was quickly copying code from something else.  Upon testing and debugging, I kept getting really strange results.  After comparing the code again, I realized that I had added an extra `=` inside of my equation:

```
Dim lowerLeft As Integer = x = +y * terrainWidth
```

as opposed to this:

```
Dim lowerLeft As Integer = x + y * terrainWidth
```

What was this actually doing?

Comment: Switch Option Strict On - Do it now!

Comment: @Oded Well technically I did, which is why I kept getting "strange results".  These are the results (the left being the strange, and the right side being the expected):  http://i50.tinypic.com/206ynhc.png  I now know that it was because it was setting them all to have a shared vertex with 0 (or 1 in one loop), otherwise; it's not intuitive (to me at least) to figure out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you had `Option Strict On` (and you **should**), this wouldn’t compile.

A `=` inside an expression is a comparison operator. Its result is a `Boolean`. In your case, this means the expression is equivalent to:

```
Dim lowerLeft As Integer

If x = +y * terrainWidth Then
    lowerLeft = True ' Converted to 1
Else
    lowerLeft = False ' Converted to 0
End If
```

`Option Strict On` rightly forbids this implicit conversion.

Comment: Why wasn't Option Strict enabled by default?  Is it not by default `on`?

Comment: @Dlamk It’s not on by default. Gods only know why. The decision not to make it on by default was a huge mistake. Microsoft screwed up here. Big time.

Comment: Alright, I went ahead into my settings and set it as 'on' by default.  Thanks for the good answer :)

Comment: Wasn't it left off by default so that there were less roadblocks to upgrading (specifically late bound) vb6 code. I don't see a reason why it shouldn't be default on for the next version of VS though

Comment: @Matt That’s the explanation often given but it’s a bad one. They could just have explicitly set it to `Off` in migrated projects. From experience I can say that switching to .NET you had to relearn everything anyway. Having `Option Strict On` by default would *not* be an additional road block, on the contrary: it could be a tremendous help.